# How to make a filter with an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to make a filter of my observable

```
private ListpplSource = new BehaviorSubject<ppl[]>([]);

  Listppl$ = this.ListpplSource.asObservable();

  ShowAllPpl(){
    this.service.bringAllppl().subscribe(data =>{
      this.ListpplSource!.pipe (
        map(items => 
         items.filter(item => item.codempresa == 1 ))).next(data)
    
         
    })
  }
```

but I'm getting underscore red on `.next(data)` it says this:

> Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<ppl[]>'.

So basically I want to my Listppl$ only get the items with item.codempresa == 1, because my service bring me all the objects, and I just one the objects which have item.codempresa == 1. And I need to use the next(data) for make it always visible

Comment: Do you want to filter data getting by the `bringAllppl()` method and then send filtered data to the `Listppl$` Observable? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
this.service.bringAllppl().subscribe(data => {
  const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.codempresa === 1);
  this.ListppSource.next(filteredData);
});
```